# Extract 1000 URI's from Twitter using Tweepy and Python

Tags: python, tweepy

I am trying to extract 1000 unique, fully extended URI's from Twitter using Tweepy and Python. Specifically, I am interested in links that direct me outside of Twitter (so not back to other tweets/ retweets/ duplicates).

The code I wrote keeps giving me a Key error for "entities."

It will give me a few urls before breaking; some are extended, some are not. I have no idea how to go about fixing this.

Help me please!

Note: I left my credentials out.

Here is my code:

```
    # Import the necessary methods from different libraries
      import tweepy
      from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
      from tweepy import OAuthHandler
      from tweepy import Stream
      import json

    # Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API
      access_token = "enter token here"
      access_token_secret = "enter token here"
      consumer_key = "enter key here"
      consumer_secret = "enter key here"

    # Accessing tweepy API
    # api = tweepy.API(auth)

    # This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
    class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
         def on_data(self, data):
         # resource: http://code.runnable.com/Us9rrMiTWf9bAAW3/how-to-              stream-data-from-twitter-with-tweepy-for-python
    # Twitter returns data in JSON format - we need to decode it first
    decoded = json.loads(data)

    # resource: http://socialmedia-class.org/twittertutorial.html
    # Print each tweet in the stream to the screen
    # Here we set it to stop after getting 1000 tweets.
    # You don't have to set it to stop, but can continue running
    # the Twitter API to collect data for days or even longer.
    count = 1000

    for url in decoded["entities"]["urls"]:
        count -= 1
        print "%s" % url["expanded_url"] + "\r\n\n"
        if count <= 0:
            break

def on_error(self, status):
    print status


if __name__ == '__main__':
     # This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter     Streaming API
l = StdOutListener()
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
stream = Stream(auth, l)

# This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keyword: YouTube
stream.filter(track=['YouTube'])
```

Comment: First of all, never share your private keys on the internet. Your authorization credentials are now compromised and you should regenerate your keys. As for your question, it's hard to know how to fix your problem since I don't know what the 'decoded' object looks like. You should print the first item of decoded and stop your script. ```print(decoded[0])``` Inspect the object - is there an entities property?

Comment: Whoops! Didn't mean to do that. Thank you! What do you mean by what it looks like?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the API is hitting a rate limit, so one option is to include an Exception when it gets a `KeyError`, I then see `[u'limit']`. I added a count display to verify it does get to `1000`:

```
count = 1000 # moved outside of class definition to avoid getting reset

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):

        decoded = json.loads(data)

        global count # get the count
        if count <= 0:
            import sys
            sys.exit()
        else:
            try:
                for url in decoded["entities"]["urls"]:
                    count -= 1
                    print count,':', "%s" % url["expanded_url"] + "\r\n\n"

            except KeyError:
                print decoded.keys()

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status


if __name__ == '__main__':

    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)

    stream.filter(track=['YouTube'])
```

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you so much. I didn't know moving that out of the class def would make such a difference.

Comment: Very welcome. Did you test it? I hope it helps. I only moved it out of the class def because I noticed it was getting reset to `1000` each time the class got instantiated. After that it seemed to count correctly :)

Comment: It definitely gets 1000 now! I tried fiddling with that for so long trying to get it to work! You are awesome! Now I just have to figure out if these urls are fully extended.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it. They appear to be, and should be since you are using the `url["expanded_url"]`

Comment: Ahh. It is still only giving me shortened urls for some reason.